# Include 'Somestring' but excluding those that contain 'Otherstring'

Tags: regex

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) SO post on excluding cases with a given string.

The selected answer there uses `^((?!hede).)*$` to exclude string 'hede'.

I have strings like the following:

```
apples_IOS_QA
apples_Android_QA
oranges
bananas
banannas_QA
apples_Android
apples_IOS
QA_apples_IOS // note sometimes 'QA' is at the beginning of the string
```

I'd like to return non QA versions of apples.

Tried (Within. Presto SQl Query):

```
and regexp_like(game_name, '^((?!QA).*$^apples.*)')
```

No results returned

Then tried:

```
and regexp_like(game_name, '^apples.*(!?QA)')
```

This runs and returns apples but gives me QA results only when in fact I wanted to exclude those results.

Then tried:

```
and regexp_like(game_name, '^apples.*[^(QA)]')
```

This returns apples results only but includes those with string 'QA' within them.

How can I regex filter to include 'apples' but exclude any cases that contain sub string 'QA'?

Comment: Try this `^(?!.*QA).*apples.*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?!.*QA).*apples.*$
```

`(?!.*QA)` is the lookahead assertion that needs to be placed next to `^` to that condition is applied to entire string since it has `.*` before `QA`.